# Kivy app lags horrendously after switching computer hardware. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, performance, kivy, driver, lag

I've been writing a program in Kivy for the past few weeks which was working fine on my laptop (Intel Core i5 6200U, 8GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce 940M). A couple of days ago, my laptop broke, so I bought a new desktop computer (Intel Core i5-3450, 8gb RAM, Intel HD Graphics 2500). I installed my laptop's hard drive into this new computer and then tried to continue coding.

Now, however, the same code/program on the same hard drive is completely and utterly laggy when I start it up. I've been Googling around like crazy to try and find a solution to this problem, but nobody else seems to experience this.

The lags occur no matter how complicated the code is by the way. I've tried to literally just create a blank screen (see code below) and it still lags (noticeable by me being unable to drag the screen around).

Even when using a super extremely simplified Kivy app like this:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class PongGame(Widget):
    pass


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

which I took from Kivy's docs

While running the program, my Task Manager tells me that it uses 0% of my CPU and 11.5% of my memory. The rest of my computer does not lag at all, but as I said, the Kivy app itself lags despite being just a blank screen.

Does anyone of you know what I could try to fix this problem?
Any help at all is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Ah I just found the solution. My graphics drivers weren't up to date. Upon updating them, the problem immediately solved itself.